# Question about Page Columns and Rows

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a Page using SharePoint 13.

Is there a way to move the columns from left to right or above to below by dragging?

In addition, can I reduce the size of columns and rows by dragging them?

Can I make more columns and rows that SharePoint 13 offers?

I notice there Edit Source. Would this be how I add extra columns and rows using the  tags>?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot drag.

To move columns you have 2 things to do, change the ordering of the way columns are displayed in the form while compiling and changing the view to have your preferred column order.

To be able to do the first you need to go in library/list settings and near the middle of the page you should find column ordering.

To be able to change the view look in the same page for views and click on the view 'all documents' (the default one) and there you can number the columns to have your preferred order.

You cannot resize them like in Excel, they will revert back to the original dimension which is calculated automatically by the system according to the number of columns VS the total horizontal space and the content of the columns.

You can change the size of columns by coding in CSS

There are limit for rows and columns and no, you cannot go over those limits.